# Position: absolute messing with div's width

Tags: css, position

I have created a panel that is displayed only when triggered, and the content is determined dynamically. 
I didn't want to mess with the page flow so I made it being displayed OVER the other divs. 
In order to achieve this I have added z-index and display:absolute. 
The problem is that cause of display: absolute my div's width is determines by the content, while I want to it be the same despite the content differences. 
How to fix that?

Check my css/sass:

```
        .panel-parent{
text-align: center;
display:none;
//display:block when triggered
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
.panel{
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    display:block;
    width:95%;
    height: auto;}}
```

Comment: add a width to the panel parent if you want it to stay the same width, you add one to the child but as you add it as a percent it needs to know what it is a percent of - as the parent has no width, then it will be the width of it's content

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to set the parent as `position:relative` and then the child to `position:absolute; height:100%`

Comment: how is adding height 100% going to fix the width?